# How to configure the remote for the forked repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

In the GitHub's offical tutorial: https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo, it recommended a way of how to configure the remote like this:

```
$ git remote -v
> origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
> origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
> upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

But I think this is unnecessary. Since you never need (and also impossible) to push to the ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY, and you never need to pull from YOUR_FORK (except you have more than one local repos cloned from it).

So, I think combine the remotes just into one origin is easier to use:

```
$ git remote -v
> origin    https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
```

In this way, you push and pull without the need of specific the remote.

Can someone tell me does this configuration have some problems?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to remote's URLs git has remote-tracking branches like `origin/master` and `upstream/master`. Very often they point to different commits; they're only synchronized immediately after `git pull upstream && git push origin`.

But if you have one remote you cannot have two remote-tracking branches. So the best practice here is to have 2 separate remotes.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate more about this "two remote-tracking branches" working scenario?

When do I need it? And how to use it?

Comment: They're reference that tracks what commit you've pulled or pushed last time. They can be used, e.g., in `git rebase -i @{u}` — git gets the `@{upstream}` from the remote-tracking branch (usually it's `origin/master`).

Comment: My forked repo is only for me. No one else will push to this repo. Do I still need to remotes to track two upstreams? What I mean is, I always push to my forked repo, the original repo pulls from my forked repo, and my local repo pulls from original repo. In what circumstance do I need to pull from my forked repo?

Comment: When you've pushed to `origin` and later decided to reset back to `upstream`… but you don't have a separate `upstream/master` so you have to look it up manually. It's possible, but why do manual work when `git` provides a simple automatic way to track two separate remotes? What real problem are you trying to solve by screwing remotes in a non-standard way?

Comment: Thank you. But, let's be realistic. I wouldn't reset the repo without checking the git history. And by using "git log" , all the history commit id are listed. Just copy the commit id and reset is simple and easy. So, it isn't a strong reason for me to keep two remotes.